# Beautiful Soup has stopped working since Linux Mint Upgrade Python 2.7.4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner trying to build a script to pull an e-book from Project Gutenberg, break it into chapters and paragraphs and then do some basic analysis on the text.

I'd got as far as being able to reliably find the chapter titles because they are conveniently in 'h2' tags. However, since upgrading from Linux Mint Nadia to Olivia, only the first few tags are detected.

Some of the fine folks at reddit have been trying to help, but we've come to a dead end. However, the diagnostics we worked on are probably useful.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/82/82-h/82-h.htm"
>>> newtext = urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(newtext)
>>> def chap_list (htmlbook):
    print 'A:', len(htmlbook)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlbook)
    print 'B:', len(soup)
    chapters = soup('h2')
    print 'C:', chapters
    return

>>> chap_list(newtext)
```

For me, this returns:

```
A: 1317420
B: 2
C: [<h2>
      A ROMANCE
    </h2>, <h2>
      By Sir Walter Scott
    </h2>, <h2>
      INTRODUCTION TO IVANHOE.
    </h2>, <h2>
      DEDICATORY EPISTLE
    </h2>]
```

Also, now when I simply call the soup object as defined above, only the first part of the book is returned - up to "Residing in the Castle-Gate, York." I'm sure this used to return the entire text. Therefore my assessment is that BS is no longer pulling in the entire text.

Versions:
Python 2.74
BeautifulSoup 4.2.1
lxml 3.1.0

I don't know the versions I was using while everything worked. Tried running under Python 3.3 got the same results. I need to use 2.7 because I want the nltk a bit later on.

Can anyone help me get this working again?

Comment: Are you sure BS is actually using lxml? If you do `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(newtext, 'lxml')` do you get the same result?

Comment: Also, what version of `libxml2` do you have?

Comment: Also, note that this document has a table of contents, so you can just scan that. For example, `soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: x.startswith('#link2H'))`, or `soup.find_all('p', 'toc')`. (To get just the names of the sections, wrap either of those in `[h.text for h in …]`, and `strip` or otherwise process as desired.)

Comment: Same result with specifying lxml. Synaptic says libxml2 is ver 2.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code with BeautifulSoup 3 and it seems to work:

```
In [1]: import BeautifulSoup
In [2]: from urllib import urlopen
In [3]: html = urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/82/82-h/82-h.htm').read()
In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
In [5]: len(soup('h2'))
Out [5]: 58
```

Note that version 4 uses a [different HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#you-need-a-parser) under the hood and I remember reading somewhere that the 3 version can handle more. Maybe you can try version 4 with a different HTML parser.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all. He was using his code with BS4, and it worked before he upgraded things. So, knowing that it also works for you with the very different BS3 library adds nothing useful.

Comment: Version 3 works for me too! I wonder what's changed with Version 4 to stop working between upgrades. I'll have a go with the different parsers.

Comment: Lazy1, you nailed it with your assessment that it is the parser. `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlbook, 'lxml')` gives the truncated version, while `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlbook, 'html.parser')` does the trick. Perhaps I didn't have lxml installed in my previous setup, so it was defaulted to html.parser, but lxml is automatically installed now and someone in Reddit says BS4 uses lxml if it is available. Thanks everyone for your advice.

Comment: @John: For future reference, it's generally better to look at the docs than "someone in Reddit". As of 4.2, [Specifying the parser to use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) says "Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser."